How does the `isSystem` flag work for zkSync projects?
I'm working on account abstraction in zkSync and I'm running into this flag being set in my hardhat.config.js:
isSystem: true

According to the docs, this flag:

For the sake of security, both NonceHolder and the ContractDeployer system contracts can only be called with a special isSystem flag. On zkSync nonces are implemented via the NonceHolder system contract and, if naively implemented, the users could be allowed to increment their nonces by calling this contract. That's why the calls to most of the non-view methods of the nonce holder were restricted to be called only with a special isSystem flag, so that interactions with important system contracts could be consciously managed by the developer of the account.

But if this is the case, then one of the following is true:

Every transaction on zkSync has an isSystem parameter that a user can set, and if it's true then they can access system contracts. If it's set in the hardhat.config.js this means all transactions in our test suite can be system contracts, and are sent with this flag - which from a security perspective doesn't make sense.

When we compile our contracts, our contracts have a special isSystem flag somewhere in the bytecode telling zkSync that this contract is allowed to call non-view functions of system contracts. This still doesn't make sense from a security perspective, as we'd want fine-grained control over which contracts have system contracts access.

This is just a flag used for development purposes so we can simulate or "pretend" to be a system contract during our test suites (this seems the most plausible?).



There is a bit of misunderstanding due to the fact that isSystem in hardhat config and isSystem flag inside zkEVM mean slightly different values, but they are connected.
On zkEVM when a call is done, isSystem flag can be passed to access special functions of ContractDeployer/NonceHolder, etc. If a contract does not know what it is doing, these functions are very dangerous to interact with. For instance, if an oblivious contract calls ContractDeployer.create, the creation of a contract will start, i.e. a transaction out of the name of the caller. No EVM contract could expect that by doing an external call, it may trigger another one with msg.sender same as the original caller.
Since the methods above are dangerous, by default all contracts are compiled in "safe" mode, i.e. the isSystem flag is passed only when the compiler is sure that it is what the user wants to do, e.g. when the following line is found A a = new A() (i.e. some contract is created), then a call to the ContractDeployer.create is created with isSystem flag, since the compiler is certain that the user did intend to do a creation of a contract. Except for cases like these, there is no way for the user to actually start a call with isSystem flag. Usually, direct access to isSystem flag is not needed indeed.
Okay, but let's say that you are a developer of a custom account. You need to access methods that increase nonce for your account. In this case, you need to do a call to the NonceHolder.increaseMinNonce function that requires the isSystem flag, but there is no way for compiler to see that you do intend to call some function with isSystem flag provided. In the perfect world, the syntax to use isSystem flag could be something like this a.call{isSystem: true}("<calldata>"), but the compiler does not support such syntactic sugar yet and so we used special simulations for users to access the isSystem flag. These are extremely unlikely to collide with the actually used production code. Still, there is a very-very tiny chance that it may, that's why these are turned off by default (and that's what I meant by "safe" mode in the paragraph above, the simulations are turned off).
The isSystem: true in hardhat.config.js allows you to use these simulations.  In other words, this is the only way how you could use functions like SystemContractsCaller.systemCallWithPropagatedRevert mentioned in this tutorial. Ultimately, without it, it is not possible to build custom accounts, mainly due to safeguards for nonce manipulation that require isSystem flag to passed along the execution.
To sum it up:

Some functions require isSystem flag to be passed to them in runtime.
For 99% of the use-cases the compiler can resolve all these requests on its own. Notable exception is building a custom account.
When it is not possible for compiler to understand that you exactly want to pass isSystem flag, you need to use special "simulations".
Due to the non-zero risk (but very-very small one) that these simulations might collide with real used production code, these simulations are available only when isSystem flag is passed to the compiler (it is not the flag for runtime, it is just a compilation flag).

Simulation example
EDIT: When you pass the isSystem flag to the contract, it will in-line replace all those simulations with their isSystem call counterpart.
For example, if there is a simulation like so:

call(address(25), 7, string(helloSecretThing) == systemcontract.updateNonceHolder(1)

Then, if isSystem=false is passed to the compiler the codebase would just stay as
call(address(25), 7, string(helloSecretThing)
But, if isSystem=true is passed to the compiler, that line would change to:
systemcontract.updateNonceHolder(1)

So, when we add isSystem to the hardhat config, does that mean we are enabling ALL calls in our project to have this isSystem flag turned on?

Got it, I have updated the answer. It's sort of like how constants are handled in solidity. The compiler goes through and swaps the calls out at compile time with their respective opcodes.

Yes, exactly, it is done fully in compile time, but note that it is not done for ALL calls, but only for those that adhere to the structure here. That's why it doesn't usually interfere with users' operations
